# CakePHP: Private Training/Course 101? Any suggestions

Tags: cakephp

I know that this question is not directly related to programming in CakePHP, so I apologies in advance for that.

Is there a website/organization where I can pay for a 101 training in CakePHP with an experienced programmer who can take me from the very basics and lead through the development my first application. Teach me best practices, answering questions, offering guidance etc. Kind of like a supervisor/mentor over my work.

Please do not answer with: ‘Read the CakePHP book’ because… I am doing that, but still I have many other questions related to programing.

Comment: Thank Igor, i will give more effort to the book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakeDC does CakePHP training:

http://www.cakedc.com/training

> "Additionally, if you'd prefer to have a more tailored training session
>   for you or your team we can provide specific training sessions as part
>   of our consultancy services. Please contact us for more information."

**Update:**

I contacted them awhile back with an inquiry to training our team, and never heard back.  Not sure if they're no longer doing it, or what.